# How replace the values of a mockup json for values with the same key?

Tags: javascript, json

im working in a reactjs project and i have a little problem!

i need replace values of a mockup json by values inserted from a input box.

this is my mockup json:

```
const createGdd = [
   {
    documentTypeId: 'SE',
    userName: 'POSTMAN',
    deviceUserAs400: 'WEB(CHROME,192.168.34.4)',
    emissionDate: 1575244800000,
    emitterStoreId: 12,
    receiver: {
        dni: '0096293000', 
        dniVerifyDigit: 'K',
        description: 'EPSON PERU S.A.',
        economicActivityCode: 'GENERICO',
        address: {
            city: 'MANZANA', 
            commune: 'PERA',
            description: 'AVDA.ANDRES SINO N.2287',
        },
        storeId: 0,
    },
    totalNetAmount: 94570,
    totalAmount: 112538,
    taxRate: 19,
    taxAmount: 19,
    details: [],
    others: {},
   },
]
```

And this is the data received from the input box when the data can be incomplete:

```
 {
    "emitterStoreId": 9,
    "receiver": {
      "storeId": 0,
      "address": {}
    },
      "others": {
       "applicantBy": "Hernán",
       "packages": {
       "packageAmount": 2
    },
       "driverLastName": "Juan",
       "dispatcherName": "IC23S0"
    },
       "details": [
    {
        "sku": 1,
        "quantity": 1,
        "description": "Bolsas de color rojo ",
        "netPrice": 200,
        "amount": 1
    },
    {
        "sku": 1,
        "quantity": 2,
        "description": "Bolsas de color negra",
        "netPrice": 400,
        "amount": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Here the final json:

```
[
{
    "documentTypeId": "SE",
    "userName": "POSTMAN",
    "deviceUserAs400": "WEB(CHROME,192.168.34.4)",
    "emissionDate": 1575244800000,
    "emitterStoreId": 9, //REPLACED
    "receiver": {
        "dni": "0096293000",
        "dniVerifyDigit": "K",
        "description": "EPSON PERU S.A.",
        "economicActivityCode": "GENERICO",
        "address": {
            "city": "MANZANA",
            "commune": "PERA",
            "description": "AVDA.ANDRES SINO N.2287"
        },
        "storeId": 0
    },
    "totalNetAmount": 94570,
    "totalAmount": 112538,
    "taxRate": 19,
    "taxAmount": 19,
    "details": [ //REPLACED
        {
            "sku": 1,
            "quantity": 1,
            "description": "Bolsas de color rojo ",
            "netPrice": 200,
            "amount": 1
        },
        {
            "sku": 1,
            "quantity": 2,
            "description": "Bolsas de color negra",
            "netPrice": 400,
            "amount": 1
        }
    ],
    "others": { //REPLACED
        "applicantBy": "Hernán",
        "packages": {
            "packageAmount": 2
        },
        "driverLastName": "Juan",
        "dispatcherName": "IC23S0"
    }
}
```

]

u know some technical for this problem??

thanks!

Comment: Do you need to merge those objects? The nested objects you want to replace it or merge it like `others` or `details`?

Answer (score -1):

First of all your createGdd object is malformed here:

```
const createGdd = [
   {
    documentTypeId: 'SE',
    userName: 'POSTMAN',
    deviceUserAs400: 'WEB(CHROME,192.168.34.4)',
    emissionDate: 1575244800000,
    emitterStoreId: 12,
    receiver: {
        dni: '0096293000', 
        dniVerifyDigit: 'K',
        description: 'EPSON PERU S.A.',
        economicActivityCode: 'GENERICO',
        address: {
            city: 'MANZANA', 
            commune: 'PERA',
            description: 'AVDA.ANDRES SINO N.2287',
        },
        storeId: 0,
    },
    totalNetAmount: 94570,
    totalAmount: 112538,
    taxRate: 19,
    taxAmount: 19,
    details: [],
    others: {},
   },//<-- delete that extra comma
];
```

if you want to add a detail subset to your element just copy your original object into a new element and then push the data;

```js
const createGdd = [
   {
    documentTypeId: 'SE',
    userName: 'POSTMAN',
    deviceUserAs400: 'WEB(CHROME,192.168.34.4)',
    emissionDate: 1575244800000,
    emitterStoreId: 12,
    receiver: {
        dni: '0096293000', 
        dniVerifyDigit: 'K',
        description: 'EPSON PERU S.A.',
        economicActivityCode: 'GENERICO',
        address: {
            city: 'MANZANA', 
            commune: 'PERA',
            description: 'AVDA.ANDRES SINO N.2287',
        },
        storeId: 0,
    },
    totalNetAmount: 94570,
    totalAmount: 112538,
    taxRate: 19,
    taxAmount: 19,
    details: [],
    others: {},
   }
];

let details = {
    "emitterStoreId": 9,
    "receiver": {
      "storeId": 0,
      "address": {}
    },
      "others": {
       "applicantBy": "Hernán",
       "packages": {
       "packageAmount": 2
    },
       "driverLastName": "Juan",
       "dispatcherName": "IC23S0"
    },
       "details": [
    {
        "sku": 1,
        "quantity": 1,
        "description": "Bolsas de color rojo ",
        "netPrice": 200,
        "amount": 1
    },
    {
        "sku": 1,
        "quantity": 2,
        "description": "Bolsas de color negra",
        "netPrice": 400,
        "amount": 1
    }
  ]
};

let element = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(createGdd));
console.log("original object",createGdd)
element[0].details.push(details);
console.log("desired output",element);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This hasn't actually copied the original object. It has modified (mutated) it.